# How to plot this transformed region?

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

I mean

```
r = TransformedRegion[Cuboid[], Function[p, 
{p[[1]]*(-p[[1]] + p[[2]] + p[[3]]), 
p[[2]]*(p[[1]] - p[[2]] + p[[3]]), 
p[[3]]*(p[[1]] + p[[2]] - p[[3]])}]];
Region[r]
```

Unfortunately, this short code does not work for me in 13.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Mathematica quits itself during the execution.

Comment: For me it gets OOM. It does not just "exit". Someone needs to try it with 64 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

r = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}];

r2 = TransformedRegion[r, 
  Function[p, {p[[1]]*(-p[[1]] + p[[2]] + p[[3]]), 
    p[[2]]*(p[[1]] - p[[2]] + p[[3]]), p[[3]]*(p[[1]] + p[[2]] - p[[3]])}]]

(* ParametricRegion[{{x (-x + y + z), y (x - y + z), (x + y - z) z}, 
  0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z}] *)

Region[r2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Edit

- To get a more smooth surface, we use `RegionPlot3D` and use `DisplayFunction` to transform the region.

```
RegionPlot3D[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Cuboid[], 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x  (-x + y + z), 
     y  (x - y + z), z  (x + y - z)}], PlotPoints -> 60, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Transform the `Dodecahedron`.

```
reg = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Region"]; RegionPlot3D[
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@reg, 
 DisplayFunction -> 
  ReplaceAll[{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x (-x + y + z), 
     y (x - y + z), z (x + y - z)}], PlotPoints -> 80, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Original**

- We can `DiscretizeRegion` the `Cuboid[]` at first.

```
Clear[r];
r = TransformedRegion[DiscretizeRegion@Cuboid[], 
  Function[
   p, {p[[1]]*(-p[[1]] + p[[2]] + p[[3]]), 
    p[[2]]*(p[[1]] - p[[2]] + p[[3]]), 
    p[[3]]*(p[[1]] + p[[2]] - p[[3]])}]];
Region[r]
```

[image]

- Test another reg,for example some polyhedrons.

```
Clear[reg, r];
reg = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Region"];
r = TransformedRegion[DiscretizeRegion[reg], 
   Function[
    p, {p[[1]]*(-p[[1]] + p[[2]] + p[[3]]), 
     p[[2]]*(p[[1]] - p[[2]] + p[[3]]), 
     p[[3]]*(p[[1]] + p[[2]] - p[[3]])}]];
{reg, Region[r]}
```

[image]